# Android Memory Profiler potential bug that crashed the app

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-profiler

My React Native app has some native implementation where I run OpenCV and Tensorflow. Without, Android Profiling, app runs smoothly and doesn't crash. With Android Profiling on, the moment the native functions are invoked, the app freezes with the following error message.

```
StudioProfiler: Studio Profilers encountered an unexpected error. 
Consider reporting a bug, including logcat output below.
   See also: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html#studio-bugs

Could not track an OkHttp3 request
java.io.IOException: closed
    at okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:191)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.network.CountingOutputStream.write(CountingOutputStream.java:53)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ProgressRequestBody$1.write(ProgressRequestBody.java:61)
    at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:79)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:216)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ProgressRequestBody.writeTo(ProgressRequestBody.java:54)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.agent.okhttp.OkHttp3Interceptor.trackRequest(OkHttp3Interceptor.java:91)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.agent.okhttp.OkHttp3Interceptor.intercept(OkHttp3Interceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Then, other warnings like below appear, which don't happen without a profiler.

```
Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: In Android perspective "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." is plain and simple. You need to avoid any task like DB operations or network queries doing on the main thread. As main thread is mostly used for handling UI updates and user interaction. However, This is not exactly the cause of the crash IMP

Comment: Yeah, there is no DB requests or network calls in the main thread, except maybe for the React Native rendering part. But the fact that it gets invoked only after I connect the profiler is weird